# Does Trim(IntToStr(Value)) make any sense?

Tags: delphi

Can there be any circumstance where an IntToStr function returns whitespace before or after the value?

I just want to make sure it is safe to delete every Trim() function around IntToStr functions.

Comment: No, `IntToStr` will never add leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: No! This is the convertion the other way that may need a trim: `IntValue := StrToInt(Trim(SValue));` because the string passed as argument could contain extra spaces.

Comment: The code author might come from a world [(i.e. PL/SQL) where converting non-negative numbers will result in a leading space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17929905/4299358) (as in: either minus for negatives or space for positives).

Comment: @AmigoJack: This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @hubalazs yet it's just a comment, because your question was not asking for a potential root of doing so - you never asked for intentions.

Answer (score 0):

> Can there be any circumstance where an IntToStr function returns whitespace before or after the value?

No.